# Problem reloading UITableView

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView which is populated by an array, I have a button on the navigaton bar which (when pressed) adds an item to the array and calls [self.tableView reloadData] in the UITableView. This results in numberOfRowsInSection being called and returning the correct number of rows (the number of items in the array) BUT doesn't call cellForRowAtIndexPath.
I have created a new navigation based application to try and find a solution but have exactly the same problem!
If anyone knows the answer it would be greatly appreciated, i've been tearing what's left of my hair out for the last day!
I have put the source for the test project up on my site at www.sofaracing.com/Downloads/Test3.zip

Comment: I should add that if i popup a modal view in front of the table, update the array and call reloadData, then remove the modal view, then it works absolutely fine! Why can't I get this behaviour when the table view is visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me! ;)

In MainWindow.xib, You added an object Root View Controller (that's not part of the Navigation Controller) - Delete it, not necessary. Then connect outlet refreshFriendsList to the Bar Button of the NavigationItem of RootViewController. Wha-la, magic!

BTW: You may need to clean up the warning. And you might want to think about creating a class for your data model instead of using UIApplication sharedApplication.

Comment: Ok I've deleted RootViewController from the NavigationController in MainWindow.xib but I don't understand how to connect up the bar button to the IBAction without that that...?

Comment: Ignore my comment, i got it! Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 1):

I quickly debugged your test app. I couldnt't spot the root cause, but it seems that you have two different table views due some mess up in Interface Builder setup.

If you initialize original array with an item, cellForRowAtIndexPath is correctly called. If you examine self.tableView instance in this call and later in subsequent calls to refreshFriendsList, self.tableView points to a different instance.

```
2009-05-17 14:33:07.591 Test3[33580:20b] cellForRowAtIndexPath 0
2009-05-17 14:33:07.594 Test3[33580:20b] self.tableView: <UITableView: 0x52b9b0>
2009-05-17 14:42:36.810 Test3[33762:20b] numberOfRowsInSection: tableView <UITableView: 0x53bcd0>
```